# Google oAuth refresh_token expires after 7 days, but for one account only

Tags: oauth-2.0, gmail, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I have written piece of code, that checks if my company application sends emails.
It used three gmail tests accounts, like `servicename996test@gmail.com`, lets call them `996`, `997` and `998`, and opened them in such sequence.
`996` `refresh_token` expires every 7 days. However `997`, and `998`, have no such issues.

I've read that this is caused by "test application", explained here: (['Token has been expired or revoked' - Google OAuth2 Refresh token gets expired in a few days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66058279/token-has-been-expired-or-revoked-google-oauth2-refresh-token-gets-expired-i/67966982#67966982)). Switching application to production requires some verification which I will not pass. This is a simple service for internal company use to check if notifcation emails are sent after certain actions take place.

I've created new account `995` to replace `996`, but issue occurs still for `995` instead.

I have to manually get new `refresh_token` every Sunday, which is quite annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching your application from testing to production will inf act mean that your refresh token stop expiring.

This is a separate matter form verification, and does not require verification.

[image]

As you can see form my app, I am in production and have been for years, but my app is not verified as it is internal just for me.

Just set your app to production, your refresh tokens will stop expiring.

Comment: My token should have expired by now, but after I changed it to production it finally ceased to expire, thanks

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Do you know if it's possible to be in production, not go through verification, AND have external test users?

Comment: Being in production, and verification are two separate things.    Without verification you will be limited to 100 test users and see the unverified app screen.