# RefreshError ('invalid_grant: Token has been expired or revoked.') Google API

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

About a week ago I set up an application on google. Now when I tri and run:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']
creds = None
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
     with open(self.CREDENTIALS_PATH+self.conjoiner+'token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request()) ##error here
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: RefreshError
('invalid_grant: Token has been expired or revoked.', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Token has been expired or revoked.'})
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: The error message is quite clear: that token isn't good anymore.  You can't keep reusing the same token.  You need to get a new one.

Comment: @JohnGordon How can I make a token last forever? And where could I do that?

Comment: In general, I don't believe you can make a token that is good forever.  You should get a new regular token, the same way you got the first one.

Comment: @JohnGordon So I have to generate a new token every week or so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

token.pickle contains the access token and refresh token for your application.

> Token has been expired or revoked.'

Means that the refersh token in this file is no longer working this can be caused by servral reasons.

1. the user revoked your access
2. The user has authorized your access token more then 50 times and this is the oldest token and was there for expired
3. the refresh token hasn't been used in six months
4. The project is still in the testing phase, and there for the refresh token will be expired after seven days.

All of the above information can be found in [Oauth2 expirationdocumentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)

the solution for options 1- 3 is to simply delete the token.pickle file and request authorization of the user again.

For number four you should go to google developer console under the Oauth2 consent screen and set your application to production. Then your refresh token will stop expiring.  Then you can delete the token.pickle and you wont have this issue again.

[image]

Comment: short answer: if you need automation for certain google API's you need PAID google workspace, otherwise you can not have service user or internal app for oatuh, what means staying in problematic testing mode forever without reasonable ability to refresh creds

Comment: @andilabs that is not true.  You only need workspace for things like google calendar and gmail.   most of the other apis work just fine with service accounts.    You can create a service user for these two apis without it you just need to store the refresh token and use that to access the account when ever you need to.

Comment: Yeah I meant this two services in particular. Hard to automate this when you want to use it in server2server setup without user clicking access. Or you have some guarantee if you keep it automatic way updating even if app is in testing/development mode?

Comment: an app in testing/development should not keep working its the whole point of being in test or development.

Comment: but then again you can't make it internal, but you relay on good will of google to make it public or not.

Comment: internal is only for workspace it means internal for the domain itself.    Google wont share your project thats up to you.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers here or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66058279/token-has-been-expired-or-revoked-google-oauth2-refresh-token-gets-expired-i) quite got me back on track, but the resolution was quite simple (and obscure):

- Delete your google token `.pickle` files and re-run your script.

In my case I'm using a Julia wrapper around Google's Sheets API called [GoogleSheets](https://github.com/chipkent/GoogleSheets.jl). The (two) files in that case start with `google_sheets_token` and are stored in `~/.julia/config/google_sheets/` along with the `credentials.json` file.

I don't know why there were two pickle files (maybe for two auth scopes, though to be fair much of Google's authentication schemes are mysterious to me) but deleting both of them causes the next run of the script to throw up the OAuth prompt in a browser window, and all is well again.

They seem to expire fairly often and there are various confident theories about why. But the reason seems to change roughly as often as they expire so just deleting them each time seems to be the most reliable fix.