What dangers are involved by setting the publishing status of a project on Google Cloud Platform from "testing" to "in production"
I have a single project created on Google Cloud Platform. It currently has a publishing status of "testing". The project exposes the Gmail API only, all other APIs are disabled. I will be the only one using this project and it is not necessary to invite any other users. I have created OAuth2.0 credentials within the Google Cloud Platform -> APIs and Services -> Credentials Dashboard for my simple Python code which uses the Googleapis Python client libraries to send an email to a destination specified in the code. The OAuth2.0 token is expiring after 7 days which is inconvenient. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66058279/token-has-been-expired-or-revoked-google-oauth2-refresh-token-gets-expired-i/67966982#67966982 this is the expected behavior for credentials issued from projects with the publishing status of "testing". The first reply in the post describes setting the publishing status to "in production" in order to change this behavior and have the credentials continue to refresh, through a refresh token, in perpetuity.
Under Publishing status -> in production at https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615#publishing-status&zippy=%2Cin-production%2Ctesting, it reads
Projects configured with a publishing status of In production are available to any user with a Google Account.
The question is, can the project be abused by setting the publishing status from "testing" to "in production"? This is part of the OP's question in the link above but it isn't explicitly answered in the post. My current understanding is that any other perspective user of the project would need to be provided an OAuth2.0 client ID credential from the project creator in order to use the project and in the case another user was provided credentials, upon agreeing to the 0Auth2.0 consent screen, only the Google account they select and log into at the consent screen would have its Gmail API exposed. This would not affect my workflow. I would like to overcome the limitation of 7 day token expiration, but I want to be sure that this change is safe. What is the complete significance of changing the publishing status of my project from "testing" to "in production" and is there potential for abuse by doing this?
